# Node Express 4 send a response after multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, superagent

I am building a NodeJS server using Express4. I use this server as a middleman between frontend angular app and 3rd party API.
I created a certain path that my frontend app requests and I wish on that path to call the API multiple times and merge all of the responses and then send the resulting response.
I am not sure how to do this as I need to wait until each API call is finished.
Example code:

```
app.post('/SomePath', function(req, res) {
  var merged = [];
  for (var i in req.body.object) {
    // APIObject.sendRequest uses superagent module to handle requests and responses
    APIObject.sendRequest(req.body.object[i], function(err, result) {
      merged.push(result);
    });
  }
  // After all is done send result
  res.send(merged);
});
```

As you can see Im calling the API within a loop depending on how many APIObject.sendRequest I received within request.

How can I send a response after all is done and the API responses are merged?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that `APIObject.sendRequest` is asynchronous so the `for` loop ends before the actual requests are completed?

Comment: Well there are loads of problems here and that is one of them. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16025166/2422544), it uses the `Async` module to make a few requests at the same time and then invokes a callback when they are all finished.

As per @sean's answer, I believe `each` would fit better than `map`.

It would then look something like this:

```
var async = require('async');
async.each(req.body.object, function(item, callback) {
  APIObject.sendRequest(item, function(err, result)) {
    if (err)
      callback(err);
    else
    {
      merged.push(result);
      callback();
    }
  }
}, function(err) {
     if (err)
       res.sendStatus(500); //Example
     else
       res.send(merged);
});
```

Comment: Wow man this is just crazy, It worked like straight away :D! Nice one. Thnx. You just have a little syntax error near }, function(err) {, APIObject has a bracket open which you must close.
Thnx again this async module rocks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't do an async method in a loop, that's not correct.

You can use [the `async` module's map function](https://github.com/caolan/async#map).

```
app.post('/SomePath', function(req, res) {
  async.map(req.body.object, APIObject.sendRequest, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
      return;
    }
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Not entirely correct as `map` is used to change the values of the array. `each` would suit better.

Comment: @Neta  I don't know waht you mean? why you think map is used to change the values of the array?

Comment: map is used to transform the data from one category to another category, map is not supposed to changed the original value of the array.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#map): `Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in arr through the iterator function.`
It goes through each value in the original array, passing in to the `iterator` and changing said value's value. At the end it returns the new array.

Comment: have you try to use map?,  map is used to transfer an array of A to an array of B, in this case transfer an array of id to and array of Object.

Comment: The argument's vain. We need to know what's the value of `req.body.object`.
Let him try both codes and see if they work.